# Split a string into an array of words, punctuation and spaces in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string which I'd like to split into items contained in an array as the following example:

```
var text = "I like grumpy cats. Do you?"

// to result in:

var wordArray = ["I", " ", "like", " ", "grumpy", " ", "cats", ".", "  ", "Do", " ", "you", "?" ]
```

I've tried the following expression (and a similar varieties without success

```
var wordArray = text.split(/(\S+|\W)/)
//this disregards spaces and doesn't separate punctuation from words
```

In Ruby there's a Regex operator (\b) that splits at any word boundary preserving spaces and punctuation but I can't find a similar for Java Script. Would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method with regex [`/\w+|\s+|[^\s\w]+/g`](https://regex101.com/r/Qg7rRW/1).

1. `\w+` - for any word match
2. `\s+` - for whitespace
3. `[^\s\w]+` - for matching combination of anything other than whitespace and word character.

```js
var text = "I like grumpy cats. Do you?";

console.log(
  text.match(/\w+|\s+|[^\s\w]+/g)
)
```

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/Qg7rRW/1)

---

**FYI :** If you just want to match single special char then you can use `\W` or `.` instead of `[^\s\w]+`.

Comment: Since \s+ has already matched spaces, there are none to ignore so the last term can be just `\W+` instead of `[^\s\w]+`. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The word boundary `\b` should work fine.

**Example**

```
"I like grumpy cats. Do you?".split(/\b/)
// ["I", " ", "like", " ", "grumpy", " ", "cats", ". ", "Do", " ", "you", "?"]
```

---

**Edit**

To handle the case of `.`, we can split it on `[.\s]` as well

**Example**

```
"I like grumpy cats. Do you?".split(/(?=[.\s]|\b)/)
// ["I", " ", "like", " ", "grumpy", " ", "cats", ".", " ", "Do", " ", "you", "?"]
```

- `(?=[.\s]` Positive look ahead, splits just before `.` or `\s`

Comment: Damn I really need to sleep. Sorry about that and thanks!

Comment: Works except for `".", "  "`

Comment: `". "` ==> `".", " "`

Comment: it does works for  "." and " " although when they are succeeded by spaces they get appended in the same array item. It's good enough for what I want anyway. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @PranavCBalan Corrected.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys it's indeed working fine. Very helpful

Comment: @nu11p01n73R :  this will work well if he just needs single special char and whitespace when a combination of space and special char are there...

Comment: Does that work for "Jack was excited! He was, elated" ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = "I like grumpy cats. Do you?"
var arr = text.split(/\s|\b/);
alert(arr);
```