# Elm function to create a list of words, spaces and punctuation from a string sentence

Tags: string, list, elm

I'm trying to create a sentence where each word, space, and punctuation character is in it's own HTML span. It would be for a language learning app so each span can be linked to the dictionary entry for that word.
So I want something like String.split but with a regex as the delimiter, and to keep the delimiters as list items.

Basically exactly the same as this guy:
[Split a string into an array of words, punctuation and spaces in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881365/split-a-string-into-an-array-of-words-punctuation-and-spaces-in-javascript),
but in Elm.

I want to go from:

```
"Hello there. These are two sentences." : String
```

and get to:

```
["Hello", " ", "there", ".", " ", "These", " ", "are", " ", "two", " ", "sentences", "."] : List String
```

I'm pretty bamboozled so far.

Regards
Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably you can just translate the solution directly to elm?

So using `elm/regex` something like:

```
import Regex exposing (Regex)


wordSplitRegex : Regex
wordSplitRegex = 
    Regex.fromString "\\w+|\\s+|[^\\s\\w]+"
        |> Maybe.withDefault Regex.never


split : String -> List String
split input =
   Regex.find wordSplitRegex input 
      |> List.map .match
```

Comment: That's great thanks. I'll have to play around with the regex a bit as I have a bunch of non \w characters ç ş ü ö etc... 

I take it 
List.map .match
is the same as 
List.map (\record -> record.match)  
?

I do notice on the github page for Regex it states: 
"Generally speaking, it will be easier and nicer to use a parsing library like elm/parser instead of this." so I was a little unsure if this is how ppl would do it.

Comment: Regex works fine, but you can do some very cool stuff with elm/parser. It's reasonably complex and probably overkill for a simple task like this, but can be quite rewarding to learn about.